# find & update one object inside array in mongodb python

Tags: python, mongodb

i am trying to db.collection.find() i want to find document with docId:'sparksLog' and then find inside it 'alerts' then object2 which has a timestamp as highlighted in the image (1602579600000), and then update last field value ( valid: true) to (valid:false)

I am using pymongo, python3.8

```
{
    "docId": "sparksLog",
    "alerts": [{
        "symbol": "ATOMUSDT",
        "candleDate": {
            "$date": "2020-10-13T03:30:00.000Z"
        },
        "spotDate": {
            "$date": "2020-10-14T22:36:56.795Z"
        },
        "timeStamp": 1602559800000,
        "alertPrice": 5.925,
        "side": "buy",
        "indicatorName": "Q1200",
        "currentPrice": 5.925,
        "changePercent": 0,
        "accuracy": 59,
        "forecast": 7.94,
        "rating": 5.9,
        "valid": true
    }, {
        "symbol": "ATOMUSDT",
        "candleDate": {
            "$date": "2020-10-13T09:00:00.000Z"
        },
        "spotDate": {
            "$date": "2020-10-14T22:36:57.416Z"
        },
        "timeStamp": 1602579600000,
        "alertPrice": 6.055,
        "side": "sell",
        "indicatorName": "Q140",
        "currentPrice": 6.055,
        "changePercent": 0,
        "accuracy": 59,
        "forecast": -3.25,
        "rating": 5.9,
        "valid": true
    }]
}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please edit your post and add the collection in json format instead of the image?

Comment: updated now, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
collection.update_one({
  "docId":'sparksLog'},
  {"$set": { 'alerts.$[t].valid':False}},
  array_filters=[{"t.timeStamp": 1602579600000}])
```